# Are printer-friendly versions available?

Tags: support, answers, printing

Many community wiki questions get [absolutely fantastic answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394?sort=votes&page=1#sort-top), and so must be read out at length.

How do I print a page of answers using minimum paper, without the comments and user avatars, etc?

I tried to copy and paste the HTML straight off a web browser into RTF editor, but it looks like a mess.

Comment: check out [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What Jonathan says is true, the print-preview is pretty good due to the CSS.

But if you want remove all the unnecessary stuff, such as comments and user signatures and the "link edit flag" toolbar, just run the following in your firebug console. (switch into multiline view first)

```
$("div.user-gravatar32").remove();
$("div.post-comments").remove();
$("td.post-signature").remove();
$("div.post-menu").remove();
$("h2").remove();
```

Now press print to get your "clean" answer page!

Answer (score 5):

When I click print-preview for the question you referenced, I don't see comments in the preview. No sidebar either - looks really clean, actually. If you want to get the avatars out of there, just run the following in your firebug console:

```
$("div.user-gravatar32").remove();
```

Then print :)

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the HTML source, there is no print version CSS.

Plus there isn't the old school "Print version" link either.

What you could do, if you had a browser that supports user stylesheets, is to whip one up and view the question/answer trail under that before printing it out.

Comment: you aren't looking hard enough

Comment: Possibly due to the cataracts - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19809/stackexchange-preview/19846#19846