# A clutter-free page version for clipping or printing

Tags: feature-request

Due to nature of QnA webpages, none of clipping services work well on SE. So, I can't clip a useful QnA to Evernote (Clipping with Clearly to Evernote is great) or any other clipping service like Readability, Pocket etc. Currently, [printing also needs workarounds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19881/are-printer-friendly-versions-available).

Please, add a feature to generate a clutter-free webpage version (with unique URL which is required by clipping services) containing only-n-only question and answers with nice design. Use HTML5 `<article>` tag wherever applicable.

Comment: For what it's worth, Chrome gives a remarkably clear preview and print. The only irrelevant content being the sharing links and 'other' tags (perhaps being just an oversight). Oh, and the time on the posts, "23 secs ago" is much less helpful in print.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment This can't help clipping. And, not all are Chrome fans. BTW, if a code block has horizontal scroll bar, try print preview with Chrome and you can see where it fails.

Comment: Try [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/), an app created using the API. [StackPrinter: The Stack Exchange Printer Suite](http://stackapps.com/q/179/9)

Comment: @SachinShekhar Fair enough, I know Chrome isn't perfect at this but only _very good_; I guess I was thinking that if they can do it (presumably following web standards or otherwise conventions) then others should be able to do a decent job of it. Maybe Google just guess, though.

Answer (score 4):

I like this.  On top of this, I would love to be able to select which answers are displayed for printing/clipping.